# Why do global variables cause trouble for compiler optimizations in function calls?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

From http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-209.pdf:

> To prevent the compiler from moving memory
>   operations around calls to functions such as
>   pthread mutex `lock()`, they are essentially treated as
>   calls to opaque functions, about which the compiler
>   has no information. The compiler effectively assumes
>   that pthread mutex `lock()` may read or write any
>   global variable. **Thus a memory reference cannot simply be moved across the call.** This approach also ensures that transitive calls, e.g. a call to a function `f()`
>   which then calls pthread mutex `lock()`, are handled
>   in the same way more or less appropriately, i.e. memory operations are not moved across the call to `f()`
>   either, whether or not the entire user program is being
>   analyzed at once.

Why is that actually so? Any counter example for why references can not be moved?

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding the text right. It is talking about accessing memory (loads and stores) on the hardware level. A "memory reference" is something like `mov [eax] 0` in x86. The ordering of memory access operations is one of the core problems of concurrent program execution (another one being the propagation of their effects).

Comment: Yes I understand. But in this paragraph it seems to me that the reason for why the compiler does not perform any reordering of instructions is specifically due to the potential of the function accessing a global variable. I'd like to know why that is so i.e. what may go wrong if the compiler would reorder and there is a global variable accessed in the function.

Comment: What if you had something like `int x = 0; pthread_mutex_lock(&m); x = y;` Then you cannot just move the load of `y` past the lock acquisition, since its desired value won't be guaranteed to have become visible until the lock was acquired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is free to move code around. The (somewhat simplified) requirement is that there can be no visible side effects.

The article is describing why threading needs to be supported at the compiler level rather than the library level. So let's consider what it means as the compiler is optimizing the code. I'll start with Kerrek SB's excellent example, since this reply is too long for a comment.

```
int x = 0;
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
x = y;
```

The optimizer sees a value that doesn't get modified but gets set twice.  The copmiler has access to the code inside the function and can see that nothing can possibly modify the value of the assignment.  Since there is no visible side effect, the optimizer can eliminate the assignment to zero and just replace it with the value of y.  The optimizer will remove it, turning it into:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
int x = y;
```

This will probably not affect anything, the variable x was local and has no other effects.

Now let's make a more problematic contrived example.

```
if(globals.hasData) {
  int prelock_value = globals.foo;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
  if(prelock_value != globals.foo) {
    // value changed before we could lock it, do something different
    DoSpecialStuffSinceValueChangedWhileWaiting();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    return;
  }
  DoOtherStuff();
  ...
```

So now we'll look at this from the optimizer's view. The optimizer sees that you read a value, then you do something that doesn't modify the value, then you test against the value you just stored. Since it cannot see a visible side effect, it might remove the comparison like this:

```
if(globals.hasData) {
  int prelock_value = globals.foo;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
  if( false /* always false: prelock_value != globals.foo */ ) {
    // value changed before we could lock it, do something different
    DoSpecialStuffSinceValueChangedWhileWaiting();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    return;
  }
  DoOtherStuff();
  ...
```

Then it looks again to remove dead code. It sees an unnecessary assignment to an integer, an unnecessary conditional since the result of the *if* is always false, and comes up with this:

```
if(globals.hasData) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
  // everything was removed.
  DoOtherStuff();
```

If you compare that to the original function, it is hopefully clear this is not what the programmer intended at all.

There are a huge number of potential optimizations that have been discovered over the years. Many of them make assumptions about when it is safe to move code from one place to another or assuming that values are only modified by that block of code. These assumptions can break badly in concurrent programming.

The optimizer needs to understand that certain bits of functionality cannot be moved, and that certain functions serve as barriers that cannot be moved across or that otherwise invalidate optimizer assumptions.